# Partial transparency on object?

Tags: transparency

How can you set up partial transparency on an object?

For example if you are working with an image plane and would like it to be 50% transparent? The Object's transparency option has an on/off option, is there a way to make it a certain percent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Cycles the most basic way would be to use a mix shader to mix transparent and diffuse. The Mix factor determines the amount of transparency.

[image]

If you use an image that has an alpha channel, then you can use the alpha as factor to mix transparent and diffuse.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a material to the plane, check *Transparency*, click *Z Transparency*, and set *object* to 0.5.