# Partial transparency in viewport (cycles)?

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

Is there a way to display partial transparency in the 3d view in cycles while modeling?

Related: [Partial transparency on object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60445/partial-transparency-on-object)

The method above looks like it only works in rendered view in the viewport which isn't very compatible when modeling. Is there another way to have transparency in the 3d view?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Partial Transparency]
Try to unselect "Limit selection to visible" in the 3D View header bar.
This works only in edit mode on the selected object...
I don't know if it's enough for your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the help mugnozzo! If there was some way to combine this with adjusting the opacity it would probably work perfectly. : ) I wonder if there is some way to combine them?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know...